# How to serve web pages from a windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, windows-services, webserver

I have a .NET windows service and I want the user to be able to configure it with a web UI.  Is is possible to serve the web UI using the windows service and not some kind of external web server like apache or IIS?  The windows service is also hosting WCF and RESTful web services if that helps.

Comment: The problem I came up with trying to host silverlight app on a web page, that was provided by WCF REST service (without web server) was the server identity. Client machine thinks it hosts web page itself so passing data from that page to server might be tricky

Comment: You could look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268814/embedded-c-sharp-web-server

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to serve static pages you can implement this method in your RESTful WCF service;

```
    public Message HtmlContent()
    {
        return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>", "text/html");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I need to be able to serve dynamic pages though.  Maybe I can just use ajax for all dynamic content so I am still serving a static page?

Comment: I agree, you can use a static page that contains dynamic ajax operations