# Jetty for NET world

Tags: c#, .net, f#, managed

I am looking for the Jetty equivalent in the Net Framework world - managed code. Does it exist? I would like to use the library from an F#/C#/VB.net application. 
"Don't deploy your application in Jetty, deploy Jetty in your application."

Comment: A similar question was once asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268814/embedded-c-sharp-web-server

Comment: You might also be interested in [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/). Also there are several frameworks listed here that are compatible with [OWIN](http://owin.org/).

Answer (score 5):

How sophisticated API are you looking for? For simple tasks, I think you can get fairly far just by using the standard `HttpListener` type. There is an MSDN sample that encapsulates it with an F# agent ([part 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297120.aspx)) and then uses it to create a simple chat server ([part 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297106.aspx)).

The core part of the chat server looks fairly straightforward:

```ml
let handleRequest (context:HttpListenerContext) = async { 
    match context.Request.Url.LocalPath with 
    | "/post" -> 
        // Send message to the chat room
        room.SendMessage(context.Request.InputString)
    | "/chat" -> 
        // Get messages from the chat room (asynchronously!)
        let! text = room.AsyncGetContent()
        context.Response.Reply(text)
    | s ->
        // Omitted: handle file request }
```

A more advanced library available for F# might be [Frack](https://github.com/panesofglass/frack) (An implementation of the Open Web Interface for .NET (OWIN), a .NET Web Server Gateway Interface, written in F#.) This also looks very easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) also runs inside a self-hosted HttpListener application in Win/.NET or Mono/Linux (in addition to an ASP.NET host).

See the [self-hosted wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting) for simple examples of running ServiceStack in a C# or F# Console apps.