# Record download in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: performance, testing, visual-studio-2012, recording

I'm going to be pretty straight forward about this:

I managed to record a file upload test in Visual Studio 2012, by deploying the uploaded file(s) to the project before recording the test.

The question now is, how do I do this for a file I want to download?

Comment: You want to test downloading a file over HTTP?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. And if possible -- I want it downloaded to a folder I choose, so I can track/measure download speed, capacity/performance of the solution I'm testing.

Comment: I would look for an embedded web server for .NET and then code it up to simulate a download.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268814/embedded-c-sharp-web-server