# How can I implement a simple server to receive files sent via WebClient in C#?

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

There is a program which sends image files in binary by using WebClient.UploadFile(someUri, "STOR", filename). I can't change that program, but I need to build a program to receive the file. I don't want to implement a full FTP server, so what should I be looking at to create the bare minimum logic in C# to receive the file? A bonus would be a solution that uses features present in .NET 3.5 or 4

I don't really know where to start, so any tip is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you just use an FTP server application and work with the files after they are uploaded?

Comment: I thought about this, it is definitely an option, but there is a possibility that I would want this to run on mobile devices as well, in which case I'd want the server to be built into the program.
Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need to provide not an FTP server, but an HTTP server (aka a web server).  From a little quick Googling, it looks like there's a library for embedding a simple web server into a .net application named Nancy that a lot of people seem to have good results with:  [Embedded C# web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268814/embedded-c-sharp-web-server)

Of course, this would be the quick and dirty way.  Probably a better long-term approach would be to create a normal ASP.Net website to receive the images, hosted on a normal IIS web server.  But if you have no experience in web development, that might be biting off a lot.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the Nancy server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions, but through more digging around I found out how to implement what I need. [This](https://gist.github.com/scturtle/1035886) is a very simple ftp server done in python using sockets. I was able to easily replicate this in C# using sockets again and I have adapted it to be able to authenticate a user of my choosing and write the received files to the disk.